# How to format query string

Tags: python, mysql

**How to format for Python:**

```
query = """SELECT u.id, u.username, a.id as author_id, 
a.user_id, a.first_name, a.last_name FROM users u\n
    LEFT JOIN authors a on u.id = a.user_id\n
    WHERE u.username='{0}'\n""".format(username)
```

When I run db.execute(query), I do not seem to get any results back, despite me executing the same query through HeidiSQL.

**In Python I receive  1054 (42S22): Unknown column "'' in 'where clause'**

I am using **mysql.connector**, **MySQL 5.6** installed.

[image]

I GET **username** from `username = request.POST.get('username')`
I pass this value to that .format(username).

I seem to be getting:

```
print(str(user['password']))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Print:

```
SELECT u.id, u.username, a.id as author_id, a.user_id, a.first_name, a.last_name FROM users u
LEFT JOIN authors a on u.id = a.user_id
WHERE u.username="erik"
```

Comment: Security advice: do not format your queries yourself!! Use formatting offered by an API or a tool like *SQLAlchemy* that protects you against *SQL-injection*.

Comment: I am running this on localhost. Python.

Comment: Can you give us the value for `username`? Furthermore note that is not only about security after all. If `username` is `"'a'"`, MySQL will get confused, etc.

Comment: See my updates.

Comment: When you use `"""` it is not necessary to use `\n` so is it possible to cause error?

Comment: @metmirr also the last `\n` is definitely unnecessary.

Comment: I removed that, still doesn't work.

Comment: What do you see when you `print(query)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I solved everything. I made some small mistakes with function returns. :-)